# Issue with my joomla left join mysql

Tags: php, mysql, joomla

right i got this working but for some reason my loop still showing the wrong values...

```
$db = JFactory::getDBO();
    $query = "select * from jos_gerencia_vendas AS a LEFT JOIN jos_gerencia_clientes AS b ON b.Id=a.id_cliente where a.id_edicao = ".$iddaedicao." order by b.nomecliente ASC";

    $db->setQuery($query);
    $list = $db->loadObjectList();
    foreach ($list as $item)
            {
            $Id = $item->Id;
            $id_venda = $item->id_venda;
            $id_edicao = $item->id_edicao;
            $id_vendedor = $item->id_vendedor;
            $id_cliente = $item->id_cliente;
            $id_produto = $item->id_produto;
            $data_insercao = $item->data_insercao;
            $pagina = $item->pagina;
```

i need to retrieve the $Id variable from the jos_gerencia_vendas inside the foreach loop, any clue?

Comment: in your code there is no attempt to show values. What do you mean? This code seems to be looping and replacing the variables. What do you do after  $pagina = $item->pagina; ?

Comment: If you can't get the id why don't you use aliases to the tables and specify the correct id that you need leaded by its alias

Comment: i show the values later, didnt placed here because would be too large, i'm just showing how do i retrieve the variables, and how do i retrieve the alias? i'm kinda new on php programming, just know the basics

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use alias to retrieve information from the query like this

```
$query = "select a.id as id,a.col1 as id_venda,a.col2 as id_edicao,b.col1 as id_vendedor from jos_gerencia_vendas AS a LEFT JOIN jos_gerencia_clientes AS b ON b.Id=a.id_cliente where a.id_edicao = ".$iddaedicao." order by b.nomecliente ASC";

    $db->setQuery($query);
    $list = $db->loadObjectList();
    foreach ($list as $item)
            {
            $Id = $item->Id;
            $id_venda = $item->id_venda;
            $id_edicao = $item->id_edicao;
            $id_vendedor = $item->id_vendedor;
```

Answer (score 0):

If you have a column named Id on both tables, then when you get $item->Id would be ambiguous.  Could you run the query on a mysql console or phpmyadmin to see if it is throwing any error?

Comment: Yes, it is, i already tested, is there any alternative for this? any help?

Comment: it showed you the right result when you runned you directly on mysql?, if it throws you the ambiguous error instead of selecting *, specify only the needed columns of each table. for example: ` select a.id as id_venda, a.id_edicao as id_edicao, b.columName as myColumnt ...`